# awk: "default" action if no pattern was matched?

Tags: awk

I have an awk script which checks for a lot of possible patterns, doing something for each pattern. I want something to be done in case none of the patterns was matched. i.e. something like this:

```
/pattern 1/ {action 1}
/pattern 2/ {action 2}
...
/pattern n/ {action n}
DEFAULT {default action}
```

Where of course, the "DEFAULT" line is no awk syntax and I wish to know if there is such a syntax (like there usually is in swtich/case statements in many programming languages).

Of course, I can always add a "next" command after each action, but this is tedious in case I have many actions, and more importantly, it prevents me from matching the line to two or more patterns.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could invert the match using the negation operator  `!` so something like:

```
!/pattern 1|pattern 2|pattern/{default action}
```

But that's pretty nasty for `n>2`. Alternatively you could use a flag:

```
{f=0}
/pattern 1/ {action 1;f=1}
/pattern 2/ {action 2;f=1}
...
/pattern n/ {action n;f=1}
f==0{default action}
```

Answer (score 15):

GNU awk has switch statements:

```
$ cat tst1.awk
{
    switch($0)
    {
    case /a/:
        print "found a"
        break

    case /c/:
        print "found c"
        break

    default:
        print "hit the default"
        break
    }
}
         
$ cat file
a
b
c
d

$ gawk -f tst1.awk file
found a
hit the default
found c
hit the default
```

Alternatively with any awk:

```
$ cat tst2.awk
/a/ {
    print "found a"
    next
}

/c/ {
    print "found c"
    next
}

{
    print "hit the default"
}
 
$ awk -f tst2.awk file
found a
hit the default
found c
hit the default
```

Use the "break" or "next" as/when you want to, just like in other programming languages.

Or, if you like using a flag:

```
$ cat tst3.awk
{ _default = 1 }

/a/ {
    print "found a"
    _default = 0
}

/c/ {
    print "found c"
    _default = 0
}

_default {
    print "hit the default"
}

$ gawk -f tst3.awk file
found a
hit the default
found c
hit the default
```

It's not exactly the same semantics as a true `default` though because it will be evaluated in the order it appears in the switch statement rather than only at the end after all other conditions have been tested so it's usage like that could be misleading.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above by tue, my understanding of the standard approach in Awk is to put next at each alternative and then have a final action without a pattern.

```
/pattern1/ { action1; next }
/pattern2/ { action2; next }
{ default-action }
```

The next statement will guarantee that no more patterns are considered for the line in question. And the default-action will always happen if the previous ones don't happen (thanks to all the next statements).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "maintanance free" solution for a DEFAULT-Branch in awk.

The first possibility i would suggest is to complete each branch of a pattern match with a 'next' statement. So it's like a break statement. Add a final action at the end that matches everything. So it's the DEAFULT branch.

The other possibility would be:
set a flag for each branch that has a pattern match (i.e. your non-default branches)
e.g. start your actions with NONDEFAULT=1;

Add a last action at the end (the default branch) and define a condition NONDEFAULT==0 instaed of a reg expression match.

Comment: Beside from the mistake of suggesting using `next` this is different from my answer how?

Answer (score 0):

A fairly clean, portable workaround is using an `if` statement:

Instead of:

```
pattern1 { action1 }

pattern2 { action2 }    
...
```

one could use the following:

```
{    
    if ( pattern1 ) { action1 }

    else if ( pattern2 ) { action2 }

    else { here is your default action }
}
```

As mentioned above, GNU `awk` has switch statements, but other `awk` implementations don't, so using switch would not be portable.